# facebook login API javascript - how can I parse value from JS to PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, api

Note: You can copy my code to run for test easily. because this API javascript not require additional install or plugin :)
Note2: run on localhost only

I want to use javascript sdk  because facebook php sdk new version doesnot support my company's PHP version.
Ok so... I want to insert the email of FacebookUser to database MySQL.
Please look at the fucntion get_Info(). I want the value of "response.email" parse to PHP variable and insert into MySQL,  but I don't know how to do because this variable is in the js function.

```
<script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {

      FB.init({
        appId: '201637766943985',  //you can copy and use my appId
        xfbml: true,
        version: 'v2.8'
      });
      FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
      FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
          document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'We are connected.';
          document.getElementById('fb_login').style.visibility = 'hidden';
        } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
          document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'We are not logged in.';
        } else {
          document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'You are not logged into Facebook';
        }
      });
    };

    (function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) {
        return;
      }
      js = d.createElement(s);
      js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

    function fb_login() {
      FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
          document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'We are connected.';
          document.getElementById('fb_login').style.visibility = 'hidden';
        } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
          document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'We are not logged in.';
        } else {
          document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'You are not logged into Facebook';
        }
      }, {
        scope: 'email'
      });
    }

    function getInfo() {
      FB.api('/me', 'GET', {
        fields: 'first_name,last_name,name,id,email'
      }, function(response) {
        document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = response.email;
      });

      FB.api('/me', 'GET', {
        fields: 'first_name,last_name,name,id,email'
      }, function(response) {
        document.getElementById('status2').innerHTML = response.name;
      });
    }

    function fb_logout() {
      FB.logout(function() {
        document.location.reload();
      });
    }
</script>
```

html

```
<body>
    <div id="status"></div>   <div id="status2"></div>
                    <button onclick="getInfo()"> Get Info</button>
                    <button onclick="fb_login()" id="fb_login"> Login with Facebook </button>
                    <button onclick="fb_logout()"> Log out </button> 
  </body>
```